# Parse timeline many to many

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, many-to-many

I'm building a parse app in Javascript.

For structure i have the following tables
Ads
Pic (many point to ad)
Activities (many point to ad)

So a ad can have many pics and many activities

Now i want to retrieve all ads with their pics and activities included
But the ad object itself does not link (point) to these objects.

I managed to get it working in the following way:

- Retrieve ads (loop)

--> Retrieve pics for adId

--> Retrieve activities for adId

This does not seem like the best way since it involves a lot of queries, could you steer me in a direction where i can use only 1 or 2 queries?

[Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mrkvD.png)
[Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fkl5B.png)

Comment: you can do it using one query. Join the table and fetch required fields you want from both tables at once. NOW you have array of that record. sort your array according to your wish like make two custom array. one for parent and second for child of same parent and run them in loop.

Comment: Hi Monty, how would you join them then? because include() won't work if my main query is the Ads which has no pointers at all.

Comment: Sample query : SELECT p.image, p.title, a.content, a.type FROM pic as p JOIN activity as a ON p.parent = a.ad

Comment: Hmm is that not a sql query? Or i'm not aware you can make custom querys in parse?

Comment: Pls mention which database you are using ?

Comment: I'm using parse.com online data structure. And coding in javascript with their sdk.

Comment: Take reference from : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24239626/parse-com-equivalent-to-sql-joins

Comment: Agreed, that's kind of what i'm looking for, but he uses direct pointers from the first object. I need to do it reverse (if that's what it's called)

Comment: If you got your answer then i am putting this reference link in answer. is it right ?

Comment: It's not the complete answer, since my method is different, but i guess it could mean my data structure is wrong.

Comment: If possible we try to give you complete answer. but sometime there is lack of resources we provide some hints, sources, links, from where you can come to your answer.

Comment: I will accept your answer it gave me a good direction to work from ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to join table and fetch required data.

Take reference from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24239626/parse-com-equivalent-to-sql-joins).